# When sharing Reactjs links on social media, meta tags in react-helmet not displaying

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a project running reactjs on the client side, and nodejs/express on the backend.  I implemented react-helmet to update the title and meta tags for routes beyond the index.  For example, the user views a post at `/viewpost?q=POSTID`, then client makes a `GET request` to the backend to fetch the data for that post which is what populates the meta tags.  The title tag is updating properly in the browser, but when I try to share that post on social media the description and title are still displaying the meta data from index.html

I've looked into react-snap, prerender, and react-static to try and server-side render the specific pages, but because I already have a backend, I'm not quite sure how to implement those.  I'm wondering if anyone can offer advice on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!!

Comment: is the client make an ajax call to fetch the post data? if so, most of social media crawlers won't run javascript when they are crawling your page, so they cannot make ajax as the client did in browser

Comment: Axios call, which I'm assuming is the same concept.  Based on what you're saying it sounds like there's no way to accomplish what I'm trying?

Comment: Some bots don't execute the javascript on your page. You will have to use server side rendering if your head tags are dynamic. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184706/react-helmet-not-updating-meta-tags