# React Helmet not updating meta tags

Tags: html, reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

I have my **index.html** page in react project as following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bucard | Digital Business Card</title>

  <meta name="title" content="Bucard | Digital Business Card">
  <meta name="description" content="Bucard - Description for bucard" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Bucard | Digital Business Card" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://m.digital-card.co.il/zedka/152/images/icon.png" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Bucard - Description for bucard" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://bucard.co.il/" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And have my **react-helmet** section, which exist in component with a path of it self on the url:

```html
<Helmet>
   <title>{"Digital card of " + this.state.card.Name}</title>

   <meta name="title" content={"Digital card of " + this.state.card.Name} />
   <meta name="description" content="Description for the react-helmet section" />
   <meta property="og:title" content={"Digital card of " + this.state.card.Name} />
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://m.digital-card.co.il/friedman/249/images/icon.png" />
   <meta property="og:description" content="Description for the react-helmet section" />
   <meta property="og:url" content={"https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/" + this.state.card.ShortID} />
</Helmet>
```

Now, the propblem here is that **the only tag that replaces here is the <title> tag, but none of the <meta> tags are replaced**.

I don't have server side rendering, I do have server side (node.js) and function that returns json of some values, that I render in my react application.

I search for almost 2 weeks but couldn't solve this yet, and this is very important to my project.
Tried also put `data-react-helmet=true` in different situations, still not working though.

Can anyone please help me figure this out? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you cannot add open graph meta data using `react-helmet` read more here: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/489

Comment: @rand0m and what about the <meta name="description" content="Description for the react-helmet section" /> tag? Why isn't it updates?

Comment: It should work, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. Here's a quick mock up: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-helmet-test check the markup in dev tools, not page source

Comment: @rand0m Hi, currently it worked and the meta tag did update, but still the image is not working when I share on social such as Whatsapp. look for example here: https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/אטליז_שינו_ובניו_-_מרכז_הבשר_החלק-VRN

Comment: Congratulations! you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ or http://debug.iframely.com/ or https://www.opengraph.xyz to check the validity of your code. It seems that the ogimage is being pulled from favicon. I think you make necessary adjustments there to suit your needs.

Comment: @rand0m yes, it does pulled from the website's original favicon. How can I make the og:image pulled from the dynamic meta tag ?

Comment: I can only think of one answer, and that's to remove `<link rel="icon" id="favicon" href="/favicon.ico"/>` from your `public/index.html` maybe that will help?

Comment: @rand0m Unfortunately, Nope :(

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, can you check your `manifest.json` and remove the favicon part from it?

Comment: @rand0m I know.. Me too... Removing the icons part in ```manifest.json``` didn't helped either.
Maybe you may want to check the ```head``` section in an example page I made: 
https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/אטליז_שינו_ובניו_-_מרכז_הבשר_החלק-GYC

The purpose is this "butcher shop" icon be the og icon share

Comment: I did have a look at that and that looks alright to me, but I still see the favicon in `manifest.json` can you delete it and clear cache and try again ?

Comment: @rand0m Changed that back. the content of ```manifest.json```: ```{   "short_name": "Bucard",   "name": "Bucard - Digital Business Cards",   "start_url": ".",   "display": "standalone",   "theme_color": "#000000",   "background_color": "#ffffff" }```. Still not working though... :((

Comment: I've looked at the source of your page again now and I still see the line `<meta property="og:image" content="https://bucard.co.il/favicon.ico"/>` can you please remove that from `public\index.html` and see if that works?

Comment: @rand0m Now I have none picture while sharing lol.
thats the output in Whatsapp now: https://prnt.sc/v0jd6r .
And if I add those lines to the ```index.html``` : ```<link rel="icon" id="favicon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />``` , it comes back to the previous result, where only the favicon shown.

Comment: hmm, leave them both to project default i.e., `<link rel="icon" id="favicon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />` and try setting them again with Helmet ?

Comment: @rand0m Hi, did this too (You can check in f12 head section), Not working...  (⌣́_⌣̀)

Comment: I have no idea on how to solve this :(

Comment: You should add meta description and tag in public/index.html. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For an SPA without SSR (server side rendering), from a bot's point of view, your head tags are in your static index.html file in your dist/public folder. To add the ability to serve dynamic elements from head tag to bots you can:

- Use a pre-render service
- Alternatively use next.js to render your pages (or parts of the page) on the server so bots can crawl this
- Look into other solutions for SSR

You may read - https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/489

An approach that worked for me:

1. Direct your traffic to a node server
2. From this node server return your index.html file and also pass head tags.

   ```
   return res.render('index', {
     headTags: ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(tags),
   })
   ```

Here, **tags** is an array of HTML elements like `<meta/>, <title/>` etc.

Bonus: You can import the same **tags** module on frontend to get the head tags for **Helmet**.

3. In your index.html you can use handlebars to read the head tags that are passed from node server and print the head tags in head section.

   ```
   <head>

     {{{
       headTags
     }}}
     ...
   </head>
   ```

and to use handlebar as an engine, add this to your node sever

`app.engine('html', handlebars.engine);`

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the comment.
What do you think is the best possible option? Is server side rendering will be that complixe?

Comment: Best option depends on your use case. If you want to render all your html using SSR then something like Next.js can save lot of your time. If you want just the head tags from SSR you can setup your own node server that has minimal code that just builds the head tags. Its not complex. I have added a brief in the answer.

Comment: @roshan Can you give an example source code for this?

Comment: @Beu Unfortunately, the codebase where this is setup is not public. But I can elaborate the part where you find difficulty.

Comment: Hi @roshan I used Helmet.renderStatic() in my server file. Its working now. Thanks :)

Comment: @roshan So you basically say I shouldn't convert the whole cllient side component to the server side? Just the headers with the helmet ?

Comment: @NaorAnhaisy Yes you can use ssr only for the head tags and you need not render other parts with ssr.

Comment: @roshan How?? Can you show my sample of code ? Or a nice guide to do this? I'm searching for this for so long

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. And solved it as below.

In your server file (say server/index.js), add
const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic() after ReactDOMServer.renderToString. My code looks like:

```
const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()
const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
     let updated = data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`);
     return res.send(updateHtmlContent(updated, helmet));
  }
```

and add the following function. This is to update html content with helmet tags.

```
function updateHtmlContent(app, helmet) {
      return `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            ${helmet.title.toString()}
            ${helmet.meta.toString()}
          </head>
          <body>
            <div id="root">
              ${app}
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      `
    }
```

This may help you :)

Comment: Hi and thank you :)  I don't have any server file, I do have 2 projects - one for client and one for server. Which one do you mean? Should I create server file in my client project and run it on different from the existing two ?

Comment: Oh without SSR ah? I meant the above for SSR. Sorry

Comment: So... How can I add SSR to my project exactly ? and one more thing I think I should say... This component should be used in the SSR and also not in SSR ,as a normal React component (I have two different situations where I need that component). What do you think I should do ?